# Iniciar ponteiro de estrutura com um endereço?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Gostaria de saber se é possível iniciar esse ponteiro tipo estrutura com um endereço, sem precisar apontar para outra variável, ou alocar memória.

```
typedef struct{

    char nome[20];
    int idade;

}pessoa;


pessoa leonardo;
pessoa *p;

p = &leonardo;
p->idade = 23;
printf("%d", p->idade);
```

Ou alocando memória.

```
pessoa *p = malloc(sizeof(pessoa));
```

Comment: É possível sim, mas só faz sentido se este endereço estiver mapeando algum dispositivo, cujo layout de dados seja o mesmo da struct

Comment: Uma segunda struct?

Comment: Olhe a resposta que já foi dada abaixo. Você pode fazer isso, mas assume-se que no endereço 1234 existam 20 bytes representando o nome mais 4 representando a idade como um `int`. Se não, qualquer coisa pode acontecer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode:

```
p = (pessoa*)1234;
```

Agora, você tem que saber o que vai fazer com isso...

Comment: Aqui deu erro..

Comment: Aqui não deu...dê mais detalhes...

Comment: Diz tipo invalido de argumento *, tem int

Comment: mostre o código

Comment: Você tem que declarar "p" como ponteiro, como você fez em sua pergunta: **pessoa* p; p = (pessoa*) 1234**

Comment: Sim , ja alterei, funcionou. mas da erro na execução, não vi utilidade nenhuma.

Comment: @user56294: Foi o que eu tentei explicar antes. Você só faz coisas assim quando está programando um driver para um dispositivo, ou programando para um dispositivo embarcado. Nesses casos há endereços de memória fixos para se comunicar com o hardware.

Comment: É como eu disse na resposta, você tem que saber o que fazer com isso...o comentário do @C. E. Gesser acima faz sentido, às vezes existem dispositivos de hardware que aparecem  como um endereço de memória, então faz sentido. Por exemplo, em DOS o vídeo é uma área de memória, então inicializando um ponteiro para aquela memória é possível escrever no vídeo alterando a memória através de um ponteiro.

Comment: opa, que legal em.